# How to display a pyqtgraph image in a form created with qtdesigner?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I've created a form, placed `GraphicsView` on it, promoted the widget to `pg.GraphicsWindow`.

Now I can plot a graph with `q.addPlot()`, but how do I display an image?

The way suggested in the examples

```
    z = pg.ImageItem(np.zeros((200,200)))
    im = self.q.addItem(z)
```

does not work with the following error message:

```
  addItem(self, QGraphicsLayoutItem, int, int, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment,  
  Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'ImageItem'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if it should be wrapped into a `ViewBox` for some reason:

```
    img_data = np.flipud(np.array(Image.open(r'd:\image.png')))
    img = pg.ImageItem(img_data.transpose([1, 0, 2]))
    # or img = pg.ImageItem(np.zeros((200,200)))
    vb = self.q.addViewBox()
    vb.addItem(img)
```